# Backbone.js: The right way to refactor view code?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm wondering about where to place common backbone view code. For example, I have the following in my "NewPosts" view:

```
  createPost: (event) ->
    #...
    @collection.create attributes,
      #...
      error: @handleError


  handleError: (entry, response) ->
    if response.status == 422
      #...
```

That handleError function is going to be used amongst a LOT of different views...I'm not sure on best practices re: where to place this. Is there a backbone equivalent of view helpers I can put this in? Any other methods of attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: My CoffeeScript is rusty, so I'm answering this in JS, but the idea should translate.

Obviously, one way to solve this is to give all your views a parent class, and then put methods like handleError in that class.  However, if you're looking for a more "mixin" like way of adding methods, you can do that too.

Backbone views are initialized with an argument to the extend method, like so:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    someMethod: function(){ doSomething();}
});
```

That argument isn't anything magical; it's just a JS object, so you can extend it using _.extend, like so:

```
var myCommonMethods = {
    handleError: function ...
}

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend(_({
    someMethod: function(){ doSomething();}
}, myCommonMethods));
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can "mix in" as many method sets as you want, whereas if you use a parent class you're much more constrained.  The parent class approach is simpler though:

```
var BaseView = {
    handleError: function ...
}

var MyView = BaseView.extend({
    someMethod: function(){ doSomething();}
});
```

so it really just depends on your particular needs.

Personally, in my code I use both approaches: I have a BaseView that all of my views extend, and I put extremely common logic (like our templating system, which most of our views use) in to it.  I then have "mix-ins" of various method sets that add additional functionality.

For instance, I have a mix-in set of methods for all views that have a "select" element as their el; this let's those views have whatever base class makes sense for them, but still also have a common set of methods (eg. they all have a selectOption method which lets me add a "selected" attribute to a particular option inside the view's el).
Hope that helps.

Comment: No, but your resulting class will.  Technically what you're doing is combining the mix-ins with your class's methods/properties just before you extend Backbone.View.  So, let's say you do `var myViewsMethods = {foo:whatever}; var MyView = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend(myViewMethods, mixin1, mixin2));`.  You'll wind up with a copy of Backbone.View's methods, except with your view's methods on top of them, then mixin1's methods on top of that, and mixin2's methods on top of that.  If all four objects had a "foo" method, it would be the "foo" method in mixin2 that would get used.

Comment: (Of course, mixin2 doesn't have to "trump"; it's all based on the order of the arguments to extend, and you can re-arrange the arguments however you want; you could do say `var myViewsMethods = {foo:whatever}; var MyView = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({{}, mixin1, myViewMethods));` and that way if mixin1 and your view methods both have the same method, the one from your view would "trump".  The only tricky part is that if you do that you need to include an empty object, as I just did, otherwise you'll wind up changing your mixin.)

Comment: Ugh, just noticed I had an extra `{` in there; that last code chunk should have been: `var myViewsMethods = {foo:whatever}; var MyView = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({}, mixin1, myViewMethods));`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a couple ways:
Define a base view with this method, then extend all of your other views from this view rather than Backbone.View

```
var Base = Backbone.View.extend({
    handleError:function() {...}
});

var MyView = Base.extend({ ... });
```

Or, extend your existing views with a helper

```
var Helper = {
    handleError:function() {...}
};

var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
$.extend(View1, Helper);    
$.extend(View2, Helper);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement an error handling model that listens to the event. You can make your own custom events or use the defaults. I built a large complex backbone.js app and it was very difficult architecture-wise until I learnt to leverage the event model. It saved a lot of handling relationships between concerns.

Create an event dispatcher and pass it as an argument to the view when you initialize it:

something like this:

```
var dispatcher = {};

_.extend(dispatcher, Backbone.Events);

dispatcher.on("event", function(msg) {
  // delegate to error handler
});


view = new View([dispatcher: dispatcher])
view.dispatcher.trigger('event', {})
```

I found by using an event dispatcher, it isolated my views, collections and models which made it very easy to test. I could just fire off events in chrome's console and watch how the various components behaved in isolation. By exposing the dispatcher to a logger it made debugging so much easier and my code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry dont have code example, but one of the concept of refactoring is to move common code to base class so all the subclasses can reuse the code.

But i really like Rimian's idea where your views subscribe for error event from an event source like object or the dispatcher. This then will make all your view's decouple from each other and handle error when it receives an error event.